# Unable to figure out the query

Tags: sql

Can someone help me with the sql query that will give me the output below? The table is below the output.

```
empno  sal    OtherCollegueID      OtherCollegueSalary
7499   1600   7844                 1500
7521   1250   7876                 1100
7566   2975   7698                 2850
7654   1250   7876                 1100
7698   2850   7782                 2450
7782   2450   7499                 1600
7788   3000   7566                 2975
7839   5000   7788                 3000
7844   1500   7934                 1300
7876   1100   7900                 950
7900   950    7369                 800
7902   3000   7566                 2975
7934   1300   7521                 1250
```

Employee Table:

```
empno   ename   sal   deptno
7369    SMITH   800     20
7499    ALLEN   1600    30
7521    WARD    1250    30
7566    JONES   2975    20
7654    MARTIN  1250    30
7698    BLAKE   2850    30
7782    CLARK   2450    10
7788    SCOTT   3000    20
7839    KING    5000    10
7844    TURNER  1500    30
7876    ADAMS   1100    20
7900    JAMES   950     30
7902    FORD    3000    20
7934    MILLER  1300    10
```

Comment: Do you have some SQL of your own?

Comment: No I don't. I was trying in Access as I am fairly new to SQL and this question was asked to me in an interview and I couldn't answer.

Comment: What is the connection between the first employee (empno) and the colleague (OtherCollegueID)? There must also be a Colleague (or some such) table for this to work, unless the connections between workmates are random or something. It can't be simply based on deptno, because there are more than two employees with the same deptno in each case shown.

Comment: No colleagues field.

Comment: The question did not make sense to me. Here is the exact question that was asked "List all employees, their salary and the salary of the person in their department who makes the most money, but less than the employee." When I couldn't answer that was the output that was given to me.

Comment: You need to do a self join and combine it with an aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

Dept_no is your tie for employees.
It looks like it's asking to find the emp ID and salary of an employee in the same department who has the highest salary after this employee.

```
Select t1.emp_no, t1.sal, max(t2.sal) as other_emp_sal
into #temp
from employee t1
join employee t2 on t1.dept = t2.dept and t1.emp_id != t2.emp_id and t2.sal < t1.sal

select t1.*, t2.emp_id
from #temp t1
join employee t2 on t1.dept = t2.dept and t1.other_emp_sal = t2.emp_sal
```

This should do it.

Comment: Thank you Ben for the answer. Unfortunately it did not work. I tried your solution on ms access with the required modifications. Maybe my modifications messed it up.

Answer (score 0):

You need a window-function to get the OtherEmployeeId out also. This is my suggestion:

```
SELECT x.empno,
x.sal,
x.OtherColleagueId,
x.OtherColleagueSalary
FROM
(SELECT e1.empno,
e1.sal,
e2.empno OtherColleagueId,
e2.sal OtherColleagueSalary,
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY e1.empno ORDER BY e2.sal DESC) rn
FROM Employee e1
JOIN Employee e2
ON e1.deptno = e2.deptno AND e1.sal > e2.sal) x
WHERE x.rn = 1;
```

Comment: Without OtherEmployeeId, you could just use MAX(e2.sal) instead of the window function and skip the outer SELECT.